# Is it possible to runserver with django without makemigrations?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to separate my project into multiple sub projects.

Model for users has changed. I have only deleted some unnecessary fields. There are no newly added fields or amended field data.

From the existing main project, I have done makemigrations and migrated them all.

For example, the User model in the file models.py for the main project would look like this.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  password = models.CharField('password', max_length=128, blank=True)
  username = models.CharField('username', max_length=50, unique=True)
  email = models.EmailField('email_address', blank=True)
  phone = PhoneNumberField('phone', blank=True)
  address = models.CharField('address', blank=True)
```

`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` is all completed so the user model is set in my database.

---

In the new sub project, the model would look like this.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
  password = models.CharField('password', max_length=128, blank=True)
  username = models.CharField('username', max_length=50, unique=True)
  email = models.EmailField('email_address', blank=True)
```

This model is located in `/sub-project/accounts/models.py`

which is generated in steps like

1. `django-admin startproject sub-project`
2. `python manage.py startapp accounts`

So, the new sub-project is totally separated with the original base project.

However, the sub project is also connected to the same database which the original base project is using.

If I `python manage.py runserver` this sub project,

`ValueError: Dependency on app with no migrations: {application name}`
occurs.

Runserver works properly if i `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Is there any ways for me to not makemigrations and run my subproject server?

I don't want to makemigrations because I am still using the same database for the main project and avoid any mistakes like migrating the subprojects' migrations.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should not make a new User model, but extend it with a Profile/Employee/Customer model.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model for how to make a one-to-one Profile model.

The User model in Django should only be changed if you need to change the way the user authenticates with your site.

So your main project becomes this:

```
class Profile(Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  # or even better settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    phone = PhoneNumberField('phone', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField('address', blank=True)
```

And you do not do any changes to the default User model.

Comment: I think my description was not sufficient enough. I made my sub project by `django-admin startproject sub-project`. The base user model is in the origin-project/accounts/models.py and the new user model will be located in sub-project/accounts/models.py which is a totally separated django project. Can you give me some other suggestions?